# at which event CANCELLATION and CANCEL_ON_RENEWAL IPN's are sent from Bluesnap

Tags: bluesnap

I have confusion at which event CANCELLATION and CANCEL_ON_RENEWAL IPN's are sent from Bluesnap and what is the difference between these events ?

Comment: I don't know Bluesnap but looking at the docs, basically the difference is that the `CANCEL_ON_RENEWAL` is sent when the subscription is set to `auto renew` [here](https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/default-ipns)

Answer (score 2):

According to BlueSnap IPN page:
https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/default-ipns

CANCELLATION
Sent when a recurring charge is cancelled. The cancellation can be initiated by the customer, merchant, or BlueSnap.

CANCEL_ON_RENEWAL
Sent when a customer requests to cancel a subscription that is set to auto renew. The subscription will be cancelled automatically at the end of the subscription period.

Is that answers your question?
Shachaf;